# android practice problems

Tags: android, mobile

I have been searching through the internet for android practice problems , but unable to find any result. I am looking for practice problems, if anyone has some ideas or resource, a humble thanks for him/her.

Comment: That's not how it's done with big frameworks. You aren't expected to memorize them like math. You might remember a lot of it after you become proficient, but memorization by drilling problems is not how you learn them. You learn them by doing projects.

Comment: yes thats what I have been looking for. actually i cannot think of project ideas that i should try(I know a bit about JAVA).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would personally recommend is doing a lot of "Hello World" Type tutorials. As Tom said, you aren't expected to memorize. 
I would look at [This Site](http://www.coreservlets.com/android-tutorial/)
This website offers tutorial projects to continue to be exposed to android, but also offers "exercises." These are basically quizzes where instead of answering questions you design an app or function to achieve the purpose asked.
Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

Try www.practiceit.com
It compiles and checks your code and uses the problems from Building Java Programs by Marty Stepp. I recommend it.